# Customizing Sharepoint form in power app - submit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am customizing SharePoint library form in Power app.

> OnSave

event there is:

> SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)

However I want to save some custom values by applying formulas based on user selection and save to SharePoint fields without user knowing via form.
How can i achieve it ?

I have tried

```
    SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);
  Patch(
       Test_DocumentLibrary,
      Defaults(Test_DocumentLibrary),
       {
                   
                    TestCol :"Ac"
             
        }
        );
```

but the above returns the error

> network error when using patch function: the requested operation is
> invalid.

I have also tried by removing the line

> SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);

Comment: Are you trying to add values to custom columns in same library? If yes, you can add those fields to your form, set visible = `false` to hide those from users. Set their `Default` and `Update` property to your calculated formula and it will be saved automatically when user saves the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add values to custom columns in same library, follow below steps for all custom columns:

1. Add the fields to your form by selecting form control and then **fields** from property pane at right hand side
2. Set `Visible` property of data card to `false` to hide those fields from users.
3. Set their `Default` and `Update` property to your calculated formula as per your requirements
4. Those fields will be saved/updated automatically when user saves the form using `SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)`.

Comment: **OR** you can use Patch function after SubmitForm like: `Patch(SPLibrary, SharePointForm1.LastSubmit, {HiddenColumn: TextInput.Text})`

Comment: I was trying by this approach but I am getting error. I have edited my question above with sample code that I tried

Comment: It's better to try the approach given in my answer. Also, while using Patch if you use `Defaults(Test_DocumentLibrary)`, it tries to create a new item. So, it will not work. You have to use `SharePointForm1.LastSubmit` as 2nd parameter to `Patch`.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Yes the above answer will meet my requirements and also your comment above regarding Patch is also helpful to me.